# How to parse a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this code:

```
var field="myField";
vals[x]=document.myForm.field.value;
```

In the html code I have

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type='radio' name='myField' value='123' /> 123
  <input type='radio' name='myField' value='xyz' /> xyz
</form>
```

But this gives me the error:

```
document.myForm.field is undefined
```

How can I get `field` to be treated as a variable rather than a field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your other syntax is correct (I havne't checked), this will do what you want:

```
var field="myField";
vals[x]=document.myForm[field].value;
```

In JS, the bracket operator is a get-property-by-name accessor.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).

Comment: You can reach an object's property with the dot notation as well. You only have to use the bracket operator when the property's name is a reserved word or you can't explicit tell the property name.

Answer (score 3):

Use the elements[] collection

```
document.forms['myForm'].elements[field]
```

[elements collection in DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357)

BTW. If you have two fields with the same name, to get the value of any field, you have to read from:

```
var value = document.forms['myForm'].elements[field][index_of_field].value
```

eg.

```
var value = document.forms['myForm'].elements[field][0].value
```

and, if you want to get value of selected radio-button you have to check which one is selected

```
var e = document.forms['myForm'].elements[field];
var val = e[0].checked ? e[0].value : e[1].checked ? e[1].value : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
var field = "myField";
vals[x] = document.myForm[field].value;
```

or even

```
vals[x] = document.forms.myForm.elements[field].value;
```

Comment: That worked, however it doesn't give me the value of the radio i had selected, it gives both radios..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags, it seems that you are using jQuery. If so, you can just do this and it will make your life much easier:

```
var vals = new Array();
$("form[name='myForm'] :radio").each(function() { 
    vals.push($(this).val()); 
});
```

:-D